# What is the maximum tensile stress of Atomic Layer Deposition (ALD) $Al_2O_3$?

Tags: material-science, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

I am looking for the maximum tensile stress of ALD (Atomic Layer Deposition) Al2o3, but I have only found this paper, where they found the maximum tensile strain:

https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3567912

However, the maximum strain, I believe, depends very much of the geometry of the test specimen.

Comment: I would kindly remind people who downvote questions to leave a comment with the reason for doing so. Simply downvoting a question without reasoning does not help the OP or the community.

Comment: -1 Not useful to the broader community. You are asking for very specific data which is not likely to be found in any standard reference book. You could try contacting the lead author (https://www.colorado.edu/chembio/steven-m-george), who is an expert in the field.

Comment: Minor comments to the post (v1): 1. In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files. 2. Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: I might have downvoted for "ALD". It is so lazy.

Comment: @Pieter here you go, I made an edit